# Adding link to CollectionView cell based on image name

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I have a CollectionView with UIImageView's in them and the images are defined in listImages array.

I am trying to get it so that when you click on a specified image, you will get redirected to a website with more information about that.

However, I don't know how to use the if clause to get the name of the image and by that give it a link.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    listImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7513-kirjatkuivumassa.jpg", @"kuppi.jpg", @"kuva1.jpg", @"juna-042.jpg", @"rautio-valamonruusut-helleaamuna-maalaus.jpg", @"pysähtynyt1.jpg", @"Screen-Shot-2013-02-20-at-21.07.38.jpg", @"sateenkaari.jpg", @"Screen-Shot-2013-02-21-at-17.04.22.jpg", @"moninaiset-e1391026376696.jpg", @"Tomperi+Metsä20111.jpg", @"3-shinot.jpg", @"Ulpukat.jpg", @"janne-e1391025808211.jpg", @"martikainen-240x240.jpg", @"takala-240x240.jpg", @"paanukallokaarme1.jpg", @"käsityök-240x240.jpg", @"kuvis-004.jpg", @"Se-on-hieno-2012-tammi-105x28x223.jpg", nil];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[cell.listImageView text] isEqualToString:@"7513-kirjatkuivumassa.jpg"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the URLs in that array? If so, you will just get an index of the tapped cell and lookup the URL in your array, assuming the cells are displayed in the order of the objects in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *image_name= [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([image_name isEqualToString:@"7513-kirjatkuivumassa.jpg"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com"]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure here is not very good. You should leverage the power of objective-C instead of trying to do things yourself. I would follow the following steps:

1. Create an object with the following properties: (1) UIImage, (2) NSString with the text, (3) NSUrl with the URL.
2. listImages should contain your objects
3. Now it's very easy to do what you are trying to do

   ```
   - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
            yourObject *yourObject = [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourObject.url]];
    }
   ```